# Convert comma-separated words to comma-separated hyperlinks

Tags: php, html, csv, hyperlink, markup

I have a problem with explode, my code:

```
$the_genre = 'Drame, Action, Comédie';

$genre_explode = explode(',', $the_genre);

$sep = '';
foreach($genre_explode as $genre)
{
    $genre = str_replace(' ', '', $genre);

    $genre .= $sep.'<a href="/genre/'.$genre.'/">'.$genre.'</a>';

    $sep = ', ';
}

echo $genre;
```

I have this:

```
Comédie, <a href="/genre/Comédie/">Comédie</a>
```

I want this:

```
<a href="/genre/Drame/">Drame</a>, <a href="/genre/Action/">Action</a>, <a href="/genre/Comédie/">Comédie</a>
```

Comment: `$genre .= $sep.'<a href=...` -> `$sep .= '<a href=...` ; `$sep = ', ';` -> `$sep .= ', ';` ; `echo $genre;` -> `echo $sep;`

Comment: Why not replace `$genre = str_replace(' ', '', $genre);` with `$genre = trim($genre);` instead. It is probably what you want!

Comment: @HasseBjörk Yes i have try this, but i don't know why, but doesn't work :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are echoing in the wrong place. Move the echo statement into the loop:

```
foreach($genre_explode as $genre)
{
    $genre = str_replace(' ', '', $genre);

    $genre .= $sep.'<a href="/genre/'.$genre.'/">'.$genre.'</a>';

    $sep = ', ';

    echo $genre;
}
```

This will return:

```
Drame<a href="/genre/Drame/">Drame</a>Action, <a href="/genre/Action/">Action</a>Comédie, <a href="/genre/Comédie/">Comédie</a>
```

If you echo outside of the loop you will only get the *last* value of `$genre` Here is a working [EXAMPLE](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/48tr-wfse)

**EDIT - additional information**

Instead of `str_replace()` you could also use `trim()`:

```
$genre = trim($genre);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are concatinating the variable that is assigned in the loop, so as the result you have only last element of your array outputted. You can use this code to achieve what you want:

```
$the_genre = 'Drame, Action, Comédie';
$genre_explode = explode(',', $the_genre);

$out = '';
foreach($genre_explode as $genre)
{
   $genre = trim($genre);
   $out .= '<a href="/genre/'.$genre.'/">'.$genre.'</a>, ';
}

echo $out;
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO. Your code is *no* different than the OP's save for a variable name change.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I apologize for my lack of knowledge and experience. Code appears too obvious to me, so I didn't know what to comment. I respect your opinion, but that actions you've done against my answer seem to be very cruel and discourages me as a newbee from answering any questions at all. I updated my answer and got -1 for wasted time and right code.

Comment: I'm sorry to be discouraging, but I am trying to help you to make your answer better. While your answer may be obvious to you it may not be to another newbie visiting SO for the first time needing a better explanation.

Comment: @SamIvichuk Yes Work :) but i have add my $sep :

`$genre_explode = explode(',', $r['genre']);
$sep = '';
foreach($genre_explode as $genrew)
{
   $genres = trim($genrew);
   $genre .= $sep.'<a href="/series/genre/'.$genres.'/">'.$genres.'</a>';

 $sep = ', ';
}`

Comment: @SamIvichuk I have an Other Problem: if use while{ } in the script, he save the other $genre because i concact the var $genre =( an solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Just avoid all that exploding, looping, and concatenation. Use `preg_replace()` to convert each word to the desired hyperlink markup.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Jhc34))

```
$the_genre = 'Drame, Action, Comédie';

echo preg_replace(
         '/\pL+/u',
         '<a href="/genre/$0/">$0</a>',
         $the_genre
     );
```

Output:

```
<a href="/genre/Drame/">Drame</a>, <a href="/genre/Action/">Action</a>, <a href="/genre/Comédie/">Comédie</a>
```